# UWP TabView Control not working with target version 16299

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am trying to use UWP(Community Toolkit) TabView Control, but it's throwing below exception:

> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key UseSystemFocusVisuals [Line:
>   35 Position: 91]'

Min Version and Target Version both are set to `Build 16299`. As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/tabview) MSDN documentation, it supports device family `Universal, 10.0.16299.0 or higher`

Windows 10 OS build is `17763`. If I change the target version to 17763 then it's working as expected. 
Any reason why it's not working when the target version is set to `16299`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the input from @Ivan, I checked for similar issue on `WindowsCommunityToolkit` GitHub site and seems that this [issue](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/2667) was already reported.

According to the discussion on the issue, Fix is already implemented but will only be available when a new version of the toolkit is published. So until then if anybody else wants to have a fix, you need to define `UseSystemFocusVisuals` in your App.xaml as below:

```
<x:Boolean x:Key="UseSystemFocusVisuals">True</x:Boolean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking this isn't the UWP control but rather Windows Community Toolkit control. As it isn't made by Windows team the documentation is based on the human input and clearly there can be errors in it. It may also be a bug, the best thing to do is to submit the issue to their github: https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question. Will raise a bug on their GitHub page.